# When merging data in r, how do we check if a record id is in one dataset but not the other?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have 4 datasets that I would like to perform a `full_join`. For brevity, I would use two datasets, `df1` and `df2` here.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 3, 4, 5), V1 = LETTERS[11:14], V2 = letters[17:20])
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 10, 4, 9, 13), X5 = paste0(LETTERS[14:17], 1:5), X16 = paste0(letters[17:20], 1:5, 6:10), X23 = 56:60)
```

I would like to know if a record appears in one dataset but not the other and vice versa. I included a column (an indicator) in each dataset before performing the join.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(in_df1 = 1) # 1 if record is inside df1
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(in_df2 = 1) # 1 if record is inside df2
```

Then, I perform a full join and I replace NAs in `in_df1` and `in_df2` columns to 0.

```
df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(in_df1, in_df2), funs(coalesce(., 0))) %>%
  select(ID, V1, V2, X5, X16, X23, in_df1, in_df2)
```

This works as follows:

```
# df
#   ID   V1   V2   X5  X16 X23 in_df1 in_df2
# 1  1    K    q   N1  q16  56      1      1
# 2  3    L    r <NA> <NA>  NA      1      0
# 3  4    M    s   P3  s38  58      1      1
# 4  5    N    t <NA> <NA>  NA      1      0
# 5 10 <NA> <NA>   O2  r27  57      0      1
# 6  9 <NA> <NA>   Q4  t49  59      0      1
# 7 13 <NA> <NA>   N5 q510  60      0      1
```

However, I would like to know of a nicer way to do this.

Comment: `merge(data.frame(df1, df1 = 1), data.frame(df2, df2 = 1), all = TRUE)`

Comment: Also,  to answer the subject  question, `setdiff(df1$ID, df2$ID)`

Comment: You need to specify the `by` parameter in `merge` if the keys are not set. In this example: `merge(df1, df2, by = "ID", all = T)`

Comment: Have you looked at `dplyr::anti_join()`?

Comment: @amandaYes, but this would not give me the full set of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's nice but at least it's the way to do it on R base.

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
df$InDf1 <- ifelse(is.na(match(df$ID, df1$ID)),0,1)
df$InDf2 <- ifelse(is.na(match(df$ID, df$ID)),0,1)

> df
  ID   V1   V2   X5  X16 X23 InDf1 InDf2
1  1    K    q   N1  q16  56     1     1
2  3    L    r <NA> <NA>  NA     1     0
3  4    M    s   P3  s38  58     1     1
4  5    N    t <NA> <NA>  NA     1     0
5  9 <NA> <NA>   Q4  t49  59     0     1
6 10 <NA> <NA>   O2  r27  57     0     1
7 13 <NA> <NA>   N5 q510  60     0     1
```